# Erro PDOException

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Olá, estou com dificuldades em hospedar um sistema php, inicialmente eu desenvolvi com o xampp (localhost), porém, quando hospedei não está fazendo a conexão MySQL pelo o que eu entendi..

Erro: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'

Como estou fazendo a conexão:

```
<?php
    try{
        $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=ipdomeuhost;nomebd', nomeuser, senha);
        $conexao ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Criei a database na hospedagem, incluindo o usuário e a senha, mas não consigo resolver esse erro, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua conexão esta incorreta. Utilize a conexão abaixo.

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!